# How to perform a t-test on a 3D array?

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, statistics

I have a series of 3D arrays of dimensions 3x3x3 in Matlab. Matlab's ttest function returned 2D arrays and when I checked out the documentation I see that the method performs t-tests on columns. I want to perform a t-test that goes over the entire matrix space. How can I code this without manually creating my own t-test script?

Edit: I am hoping to get two outputs that contain the p-values and t-values output by the ttest method like in

[~,pval,~,tval] = ttest(x,y)

but thise only gives the 2D arrays mentioned above. I require the output be a 3x3x3 array giving the t-value at each point, and ideally another that contains the p-value corresponding to those t-values.

Comment: I suppose I was unclear as to my needs. You point out something that is true, but I am hoping to obtain outputs from ttest that give me the p-values and t-values at each point in the array. I have added to my post to clear this up. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I am still not explaining myself correctly.

The images I have are 3D arrays of count values for a PET imaging session. I want to perform a t-test comparing subsequent frames in the study to the first, and have output be new arrays containing the t-values show for each individual voxel when compared to the entire image.

Comment: Ah! So you want to (1) concatenate the images to a single 4D array (using `cat(4,img1,img2,img3,...)`, if you have a cell array with them, then `cat(4,img{:})` will do it), (2) permute the array so that the new dimension is the first one (the column), and then (3) apply the statistics along the columns. Often MATLAB functions allow you to select a dimension along which to work, so you can skip step 2. If you can't skip step 2, maybe it's more efficient to reshape the images and concatenate directly along your desired dimension. If all images don't fit in memory, you'll have to loop.

Comment: I will try this out and let you know how this goes. Thank you very much for your help. I am a long-time reader but first-time poster to SE and I really appreciate your attention.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I have attempted to do as you've suggested but am still receive 2D outputs from ttest, I concatenate everything along an empty 4th dimension and then permute the dimensions so the empty dimension is the first as you suggest. Then I run a ttest. Does Matlab is automatically suppress an empty dimension?

Comment: What is the size of the output? The docs say “ttest performs a separate t-test along each column and returns a vector of results.” So maybe you’re getting the right data but in the wrong shape.